# Use of extension functions in streaming mode in Saxon/Net

Tags: saxon

I would like to know whether it is possible to call user extension functions in streaming mode using XSLT 3.0 on Saxon EE for .Net.

And if it is, under what constraints (e.g. "never pass nodes as parameters but atomic values are OK", etc.)

I have looked at the main documentation but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's been tested, so I suggest you try it and see. The streamability analysis uses the general streamability rules, so if you pass atomic values (or unstreamed nodes) then it should be OK. You might be able to get away with passing nodes as well, provided you don't try doing any downwards navigation from them. If you pass a sequence of nodes rather than a single node then they may get buffered.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you.  Makes perfect sense and is promising in my case.  I will try it and post my findings here.  Given what I need to achieve, I think using `copy-of()` would be fine, but I think it would not even be necessary, atomic values should do it.